# Module Import Error in the Standalone Player

Tags: game-engine, import

I am using Blender 2.71 and Ubuntu 14.04

I've got a module, external to Blender, installed thanks to its `setup.py` inside my `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` (the result of the build is an `.so` file).

After copying this one inside `<my_blender_folder>/scripts/addons/` , it's working, but only when using the Embedded Player; When using the Standalone Player, the module is *not found anymore*.
I've tried to copy the `.so` file inside the folder where the Blender executable is, but it's not found either.

Why is this module not being found, when using the Standalone Player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module, to be correctly found by the standalone player, must be placed inside `<my_blender_folder>/2.71/python/lib/python3.4/`.

So it's completely different from the embedded player (used normally by hitting `p` in the game engine) (which is `<my_blender_folder>/2.71/scripts/addons/`)

I finally found it by using a `import sys; print(sys.path)` and using the standalone player.

This info doesn't seem to be found anywhere in the API docs strangely.